# Prevent direct access to html page in node js

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to prevent the user from directly typing in the url of the page and getting led to the page.
How can I achieve this functionality in node ?
I know that in web applications placing the files under the WEB-INF folder prevent direct access to them.

Comment: You can check referer, but scrapers can bypass that pretty easily.  The average human will get blocked, though.  Think before you do this.  It can cause usability issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [`Express`](http://expressjs.com/api.html) you can check referer in middleware with something like this, which you should adapt further as needed for your exact purposes:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

permittedLinker = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1'];  // who can link here?

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var i=0, notFound=1, referer=req.get('Referer');

  if ((req.path==='/') || (req.path==='')) next(); // pass calls to '/' always

  if (referer){
      while ((i<permittedLinker.length) && notFound){
      notFound= (referer.indexOf(permittedLinker[i])===-1);
      i++;
      }
  }

  if (notFound) { 
     res.status(403).send('Protected area. Please enter website via www.mysite.com');
  } else {
    next(); // access is permitted, go to the next step in the ordinary routing
  }
});

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.send('<p>Hello.  You are at the main page. </p><a href="page2">page 2</a>');
});

app.get('/page2', function(req,res){
    res.send('<p>You are at page 2</p>');
});

app.listen(3000);  // test at http://localhost:3000
```

## Testing (and Countermeasures)

Can we get the main page? **Yes**

```
wget http://localhost:3000/

--2014-10-10 04:01:18--  http://localhost:3000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:3000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
200 OK
Length: 67 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’
```

Can we get the second page directly? **No**

```
wget http://localhost:3000/page2
--2014-10-10 04:04:34--  http://localhost:3000/page2
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:3000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2014-10-10 04:04:34 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

Can we get the second page from the first page? **Yes**

```
 wget --referer="http://localhost" http://localhost:3000/page2
--2014-10-10 04:05:32--  http://localhost:3000/page2
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:3000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
200 OK
Length: 24 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘page2’
```

Can any script kiddie learn to use wget --referer to defeat this "protection" scheme?

**Yes. It only blocks honest people.  Not someone who really wants the contents.**