# How to prevent direct access to file in Node but allow server to load file?

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have multiple dynamic directories that I want to prevent the user from accessing, but I'd like the server to load those files.

My structure is as follows but does grow dynamically so I can't statistically name the files:

- views/mods/headers/john/
- views/mods/headers/john/meta/screenshot.png
- views/mods/headers/john/index.html
- views/mods/headers/john/style.css

How do I provide access to the `folder john` for the server and not a user trying to view it directly?, as well as `screenshot.png, index.html and style.css`?

Fairly new to Node so I'm not that sure, but in .htaccess it would be something like this: [(htaccess) How to prevent a file from DIRECT URL ACCESS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236717/htaccess-how-to-prevent-a-file-from-direct-url-access)

Thanks.

Comment: Probably this can help. [prevent direct access to html page in node js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293380/prevent-direct-access-to-html-page-in-node-js)